# Как преобразовать текстовые значения в числовые типы данных Access ado net

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net, ms-access

Извините за вопрос, я только учусь, я видел [эту ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397083/how-to-convert-text-values-to-access-numeric-data-types), но я все еще не понимаю

У меня есть приложение, в котором wpf отображает данные из базы данных аксес. Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении в wpf он менялся и в базе данных аксес.

Код ниже

```
#region UPDATE
            var accessUpdate = $@"UPDATE ORDERS SET 
                       email = @emailAccess,
                       product_number = @product_number, 
                       product_name = @product_name
                       WHERE Id = @idAccess";

            daAccess.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(accessUpdate, accessConnection);
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@idAccess", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Id");
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@emailAccess", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "email");
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_number", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_number");
            daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@product_name", OleDbType.WChar, 0, "product_name");
#endregion
```

при попытке изменить данные выходит ошибка
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Я понимаю, что проблема в поле id и понимаю, что нужно привести его к int, но совершенно не понимаю, как этого не делать

idAccess это имя текст колум в впф

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="gridViewAccess" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                      CurrentCellChanged="ChangedAccess" 
                      CellEditEnding="ChangedEndingAccess" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idAccess" 
                                Binding="{Binding Id}" 
                                Header="Id" 
                                IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailAccess" 
                                Binding="{Binding email}" 
                                Header="email"/>...
```

Попробовал сделать вот так. Выходит ошибка

```
daAccess.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@idAccess", OleDbType.Integer, 0, "Id").Value =
        Convert.ToInt16(gridViewAccess.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю он говорит, что не чего еще не выбрано, поэтому так сделать нельзя, а как надо то?

Comment: .Parameters.AddWithValue("@idAccess", 5); //5 - value - подставьте своё значение

Comment: @Konst я заполняю командами дата атаптер еще до того как начинают происходить изменения, соответсвенно еще не чего не выбрано и на этом этапе я еще не знаю какое число там будет, а при попытке указать селектид он говорит что вернул нулл

Comment: сделайте значение по умолчанию

Comment: @Konst Я попробовал ради интереса вот так Parameters.AddWithValue("@idAccess", 5); он все равно говорит что тип данных не соответствует

Comment: на сколько я помню, OleDbCommand для Access не поддерживает именованных параметров, вам надо переписать запрос с параметрами через ? и добавлять параметры в команду в нужной последовательности

Comment: Вообщем то я не че не понял) я короч перенес запрос в момент собственно изменения запроса и сделал вот это                                                                                                                                     TextBlock selectedTextBlock = gridViewAccess.Columns[0].GetCellContent(gridViewAccess.Items[gridViewAccess.SelectedIndex]) as TextBlock;
int selectedId = int.Parse(selectedTextBlock?.Text);
var accessUpdate = UPDATE ORDERS SET ...
                           
                           WHERE Id = {selectedId}";                     UpdateCommand с id удалил